# Showing many images in a WPF view overheads too much memory

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I am developing a WPF application and I need to show 7200 images in a window.
Each image size is equals to 300x300.
My code "*.xaml" is showed below:

```
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="180">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
                                <Label Content="{Binding Frame}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">  
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding FrameImage}"/>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Image Source="{Binding FrameImage}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="2">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding FrameMatch}"/>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Image Source="{Binding FrameMatch}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="2">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ObjMatch}"/>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ObjMatch}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="4" Margin="2">

                                <Image Source="{Binding ObjImage}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="5" Margin="2">
                                <Label Content="{Binding Fitness}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is that the program consume to much memory.
It is possible to overcome this problem ?
Can anybody give me a solution ?

Comment: Try to "virtualize" your UI    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: What part of you statement is "this problem"? I don't believe "to much memory" is right statement, probably should be "I don't like how much memory it consumes even if I know all it is needed due to my requirement to load at least 7200 * 360K bytes (~2.5GB) at the same time".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Now I am reading about virtualizing the UI and I found my answer, thanks to Reed Copsey, before a was finding a way to release the resources of the images when that was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is possible to overcome this problem ? Can anybody give me a solution ?

Don't show 7200 300x300 images *at the same time*.  This is far more than any monitor(s) will be able to display at once, so it would be better to virtualize this, and only show the images that are on screen.

This can be done by using a [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx), or even implementing a custom control with [bidirectional virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx#Supporting).